# Как сделать функцию Heapsort для 2D массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Тема: Разработка программы на С++ для сортировки массива методом (Heapsort).
Задание:

1. Разработать функцию на С++ для сортировки массива по методу Heapsort.
2. Создать матрицу (3х5) и заполнить ее случайными числами.
3. Произвести сортировку матрицы, используя разработанную функцию.

Сначала я сделал просто массив  в формате 1D, сделав его динамическим я мог вставить его размер (15) и затем просто через уже созданную функцию HeapSort все числа ставали в правильном порядке. Далее я создал 2D массив и заполнил его случайными числами и перешел на этап  переделки функции в 2Д. Наткнулся на готовый код на Java (https://www.justinlog.com/heapsort-2d-and-option-for-min-max-heap), но в меру своих сил не могу адекватно проанализировать этот пример и перенести или реализовать его на C++.

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include<iomanip>
     #include<cstdlib>
     using namespace std;
                  
     int main()
    {
    int k, temp;
    const int n = 3, m = 5;
      int ar[n][m];
       srand(time(NULL));


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
         ar[i][j] = rand() % 90;
              }

          }
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
               cout << ar[i][j] << " ";
          }
        cout << endl;
        }
                                  //Функция для 1Д сортировки
           void heap()
        {
        int max = i;
       while (true)
        {
        int left = 2 * i + 1;  // left half
        if (left < n && a[left] > a[max])
            max = left;
        left++;               // raight half
        if (left < n && a[left]  > a[max])
            max = left;
        if (max == i)
            break;
        else {

            std::swap(a[max], a[i]);
            i = max;
        }


    }


}
                                  
  void heapsort() {

    for (int i = n / 2; i >= 0; i--)
        heap(a, i, n);     // create heap
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        std::swap(a[0], a[i]);
        heap(a, 0, i);

    }
```

Comment: А что значит сортировка двумерная? Одномерная просто, из `i>j` следует `a[i] >= a[j]` (ну, или меньше или равно). А как записать условие для двумерной сортировки?

Comment: @Mikhailo
Нам нужно сортировать числа в матрице.(Под этим как я понял и подразумеваться двумерная сортировка . Как записать условие? -А нельзя ли просто применить  уже готовый вариант для 1д сортировки?

Comment: Сама она не двумерная, это массив двумерный , если только так можно сказать .

Comment: Я и спрашиваю - как сортировать двумерный массив? Не о программе, а о принципе Каждую строку отдельно? Столбец? Все числа отсортировать и разместить построчно? Постолбцово? Змейкой? Это все совершенно разные сортировки!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Двумерный массив в памяти располагается построчно как одномерный. Т.е. двумерный массив 3x4 в памяти выглядит точно так же как одномерный массив из 12 элементов.
Используйте арифметику указателей. Возьмите указатель на массив и работайте со смещениями указателей. Т.е. в функции одномерной сортировки вместо взятия значения по двум  индексам, берите значение от указателя:

```
int* p = ar;
if (left < n && a[left] > a[max]) {} // аналогично
if (left < n && *(p + left) > *(p + max) ) {}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
   {
     ar[i][j] = rand() % 90;
   }
// аналогично
for (int i = 0; i < n*m; i++)
  {
    *(ar + i) = rand() % 90;
  }
```

Только не забывайте, что теперь размер одномерного массива - n*m.
Если для двумерной индексации, то индекс считается так:

```
ar[i][j] == *(ar + i*m + j)  // эти записи идентичны
                             // обращение к одному и тому же элементу
```

Если ещё учесть, что сортировка кучей (пирамидой) на самом деле сортирует бинарное дерево, которое просто записано (хранится в памяти) последовательно в массив то получается вообще красиво - вы сортируете двумерный массив, записанный как бинарное дерево в одномерный массив. :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ (изначально я и пытался использовать указатели). У меня возникла проблема с внедрением в код вашего ответа , не могли б вы ещё помочь с решением и показать целиком всё в коде?

Comment: Это если именно `array[][]`. А если будет `int**`?

Comment: А зачем? Указатель на ячейку памяти в которой хранится указатель на int ? И что это даст? Нужно понимать как данные хранятся в памяти и как можно обращаться к ним.  Если мы говорим о массиве, то достаточно int* - и неважно какой размерности массив - двумерный или n-мерный.

Comment: `ar[i][j] == *(ar + i*j + j)` — это неверно. Да и вообще, работа с многомерным массивом как с одномерным вызывает неопределённое поведение. [C, n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): «J.2 Undefined behavior ...  An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration `int a[4][5]`) (6.5.6).» Впрочем, кого эти стандарты вообще волнуют...

Comment: @wololo @wololo Да, действительно в формуле ошибся, спасибо. Для массива `int a[N][M]` правильная формула будет ` *(a + i*M + j) `. Я только "за" за стандарты и очень их уважаю. И здесь не идет речи "о работа с многомерным массивом как с одномерным" в Вашем контексте. Речь здесь идет о другом - как данные физически хранятся в памяти и как к ним можно получить доступ.

Comment: @wololo Просто имея адрес начала массива по нему можно пройти как по одномерному, независимо от того, какой размерности он объявлен. И всё работает без неопределенного поведения: `int *p = &a[0][0];` или `int *p = a[0]; ` и дальше проход указателем по массиву, как по одномерному `cout << *(p + i*M + j);`

Comment: Если вы знаете как многомерный массив физически хранятся в памяти, то это не значит, что используя арифметику указателей, вы можете просто пройтись по нему как по одномерному. [Тест](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de9561444a51c94b).

Comment: @wololo Прекрасно можно пройтись ~static constexpr int arr[2][10] = {};
    int* p1 = const_cast<int*>(&arr[0][0]);
    cout << *(p1+11);
    ~ И при чем тут константность?

Comment: Цитаты из стандарта языка — не аргумент. Пример программы, где компилятор прямым текстом пишет «array subscript value '11' is outside the bounds of array type 'const int [10]'» — не аргумент. `Прекрасно можно пройтись...` Угу, а локальные переменные всегда инициализируются нулём. [«Пруф»](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/187eba7e86eb3e31).

Answer (score 0):

Странно, какие проблемы могли возникнуть?
Вот ваша функция сортировки, как она написана в вопросе.

```
void heap()
{
    int max = i;
    while (true)
    {
        int left = 2 * i + 1;  // left half
        if (left < n && *(a + left) > *(a + max))
            max = left;
        left++;               // right half
        if (left < n && *(a + left)  > *(a + max))
            max = left;
        if (max == i)
            break;
        else 
        {
            std::swap(*(a + max), *(a + i));
            i = max;
        }
    }
}
```

В таком виде она конечно не работает - вы используете в функции переменные, которые туда никак не попадали. А в main() вы даже не вызываете эти функции.
Но! Вы написали, что у вас **работает** программа для одномерного массива. Вот и подставьте в работающую программу код функции сортировки и всё будет работать!
Вопрос был - для одномерного массива сортировка работает, а для двумерного не получается. Я написал как сделать для двумерного массива.
Если вопрос - "напишите мне программу сортировки", то вы зашли не на тот сайт.